# Unable to access hosted site from another PC on network

Tags: html, iis, networking

I am trying to connect to a site that I am hosting via IIS on Computer A and trying to connect to it via Computer B and an iPad but I am getting a "This site can't be reached" error.

On Computer A I have bindings:

Type | Host Name | Port | IP Address

http | example   | 80   | *

http | example   | 80   | 192.168.0.13

I also have hosts file pointing to hostname and IP address.

When connecting via Computer A everything is fine an works as expected, Computer B and iPad on the other hand are not able to connect.

I have also attempted to create a rule to allow inbound on port 80 but still no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated, more information can be provided if needed.

Comment: Do Computer A, Computer B and iPad connected to same modem/router?

Comment: 1292.168.0.13 IP adress is incorrect

Comment: @Vykintas Corrected typo on up address unfortunately that was only in the question, well spotted. And yes they all connect to the same router since it is at home.

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: @LexLi do you think there is anything basic I might have missed? First time attempting this

Comment: For other devices, they have no way to associate "example" with Computer A (without a DNS server), so http://example won't work on any of them. If you do run Binding Diagnostics and report its report, that should be clear.

Comment: @LexLi do you know of any guides start to finish that would explain the process from setting up the site all the way to connecting via a different pc on the same network? Sort of lost and not sure where to start

Comment: Without a DNS server in that network, please remove host name from bindings, and merely use `http://IP address`. To study DNS and the related concepts, you can find tons of books/resources via a search engine.

Comment: @LexLi I have multiple sites running from the same pc would that not conflict since they have the same IP address?

Comment: In your case, you might 1) assign multiple IP addresses to this PC, so each sites bind to a single IP. 2) learn how to set up DNS. Asking for tutorials is off-topic here.

Comment: @LexLi will look into both of them, only asking for a little direction

Comment: I don't know about IIS, but for example NGINX works width default config if you only open a port 80 in ROUTER (or 8080 if not admin). So firstly I would start here. And IIS is part of Windows, so I would check windows firewall secondly.

Comment: Seen option when IIS have many sites on same IP but different ports, maybe you using different port, not 80?